# VS Code can't download symbols for test app

Tags: visual-studio-code, automated-tests, dynamics-business-central

I would like to create a test environment for my app running in BC18, but I have trouble downloading the necessary symbols. I created a new workspace along with a `.vscode/launch.json`  and an `app.json`-file, which contains the following properties:

```
"dependencies": [
        {
            "id": "65d313b7-f655-41af-9325-3ade0d3489e9",
            "name": "Main App",
            "publisher": "My Company",
            "version": "1.0.1.0"
        }
    ],
    "test": "17.0.0.0"
```

However, when trying to download the symbols, I always get the following error:

```
[2021-05-18 15:39:06.44] The request for path /BC/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=Test&versionText=17.0.0.0&tenant=default failed with code NotFound. Reason: No published package matches the provided arguments.
[2021-05-18 15:39:06.44] The following dependencies will be queried for propagated dependencies:
Application by Microsoft (18.0.0.0)
[2021-05-18 15:39:06.44] Sending request to http://ll-bc-at:7049/BC/dev/packages?publisher=Microsoft&appName=Application&versionText=18.0.0.0&tenant=default
[2021-05-18 15:39:06.45] Could not download reference symbols. Please ensure that:
1. The correct server name and instance are specified in the launch.json file.
2. The correct application version is specified in the app.json file.
3. The dependencies are correctly specified in the app.json file.
```

I've tried reinstalling the container, making sure the test toolkit is included and confirmed it is working properly by accessing the default test suite in the Test Tool, but nothing so far has been successful. Using different version for `test` hasn't had an effect either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `test` property has been deprecated. You will need to add the dependecies for the various test extensions you want to use.

I normally use these dependencies as a starting point:

```
{
    "id": "e7320ebb-08b3-4406-b1ec-b4927d3e280b",
    "name": "Any",
    "publisher": "Microsoft",
    "version": "17.0.0.0"
},
{
    "id": "23de40a6-dfe8-4f80-80db-d70f83ce8caf",
    "name": "Test Runner",
    "publisher": "Microsoft",
    "version": "17.0.0.0"
},
{
    "id": "dd0be2ea-f733-4d65-bb34-a28f4624fb14",
    "name": "Library Assert",
    "publisher": "Microsoft",
    "version": "17.0.0.0"
},
{
    "id": "9856ae4f-d1a7-46ef-89bb-6ef056398228",
    "name": "System Application Test Library",
    "publisher": "Microsoft",
    "version": "17.0.0.0"
},
{
    "id": "5d86850b-0d76-4eca-bd7b-951ad998e997",
    "name": "Tests-TestLibraries",
    "publisher": "Microsoft",
    "version": "17.0.0.0"
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Everywhere I looked so far only used the `test` property and I didn't get a warning about it being deprecated, so I didn't think that would be the problem.

Comment: I understand that. The documentation regarding this could certainly be improved.